# Using putchar and printf together in the same C Program?

Tags: c, standard-library

I've written a small C program where I wanted to display the numeric ASCII value that corresponds to certain key presses.

My code follows. The problem is, after running the program, it accepts input, but doesn't do anything else. It doesn't even reach the first printf statement. I can't figure out what the issue is - **is there a problem with mixing the getchar() function with the printf() function in the same program?**

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {

    const int numKeys = 256;

    int keys[numKeys];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {

        keys[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("\n Start pressing some keys!\n\n");

    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

        printf(" CAPTURED: %d\n", c);

        keys[c]++;
    }

    printf("\n\n ** RESULTS ** \n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < numKeys; i++) {

        if (keys[i] != 0) {

            printf(" Key with value %d was called %d times.", i, keys[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I should clarify that I have a Windows XP Pro machine, with Cygwin installed. I use Cygwin for my development space, so I wonder if there is something different when running this type of program in that environment.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with mixing them, as getch effects stdin, while printf effects stdout. I think the problem might be elsewhere?

Comment: Are you pressing enter?

Comment: it doesnt reach `printf("result")` or `printf(captured)`?.if its the former then its right in doing so because how will it break the `while loop` if you dont get `EOF`. `getchar` waits for `\r\n` or`Enter` to be pressed. use getche. but even then you will have the first issue

Comment: Your program works fine for me, but then again, I'm running Ubuntu Linux.  ctrl+d gives me an EOF, I would imagine Windows has something similar.  For interesting reading, look at http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html to discover ways to read in a character from stdin without having to press enter.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I think you want to use

`while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')`

Instead if you want to have it print the results after the person hits enter/return.

Answer (score 0):

problem 1 : getting to `printf(" CAPTURED: %d\n", c);` without having to press the `Enter` key 
solution : is by using `getche()` in while loop.

problem 2 : getting to 'printf("\n\n ** RESULTS ** \n\n");' or essentially breaking while loop?

solution : **you cannot**. you will never get `EOF` as long as you read from keyboard. 
workaround : close stdin or use a escape character other than `EOF`.

EDIT : workaround2 : 
->use getchar() itself. but to print those entered char u need to press `Enter` key. now on windows `ctrl+z` gives `EOF` but this should be the `**FIRST**` input on the line after you press `Enter` key. well this is not a good solution.

if you want a **"Press key display times pressed scenario. there is just no simple way(AFAIK)"**

Comment: ctrl+d gives me EOF on my Ubuntu Linux

Comment: ctrl+Z should give EOF in windows. but there is a condition. i'l edit my post based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the first `printf` statement gets executed, but due to buffering is not displayed on the screen immediately. Use `fflush(stdout)` to send the contents of the buffer to the screen. Ie:

```
printf("\n Start pressing some keys!\n\n");
fflush(stdout);
```